# Django: Table template

Tags: html, django, html-table

I have this table in my template

```
<tr>
   <th>SCHEDULE OF FEES</th>
   <th colspan="2">SCHEDULE OF PAYMENT</th>
</tr>
{% for FeesType in SchoolFeesType %}
     <tr>
        <td>{{FeesType.School_Fees_Type}}: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8369; {{FeesType.Amount}}</td>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
{% for Fees in scheduleofpayment %}
      <tr>
          <td >{{Fees.Remark}}</td>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

as you can see in my code I have two loop with different models, the **SCHEDULE OF FEES** and **SCHEDULE OF PAYMENT**

[image]

as you can see in the picture I just want to move the result of scheduleofpayment to **SCHEDULE OF PAYMENT** but I don't know how, can ypu please guys help me?

Comment: "tr" means "table row". So first row contains 2 cells, the others - only one. You could `zip` your lists to one and iterate it if they were the same length... In form of table it will be very complicated template, worthless efforts.

Comment: You can't use one `<table>` for this, because tables work row by row and in your case your columns are unrelated. Either put two tables next to each other or use two `<div>` blocks that you put next to each other (by using [css flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)).

Comment: mr @dirkgroten that's make sense, can you post your answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use one `<table>` for this, because tables work row by row and in your case your columns are unrelated. Either put two tables next to each other or use two `<div>` blocks that you put next to each other.

In both cases, I'd recommend using [css flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), so you can control the height and alignment of your individual columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <tr>
       <th>SCHEDULE OF FEES</th>
       <th colspan="2">SCHEDULE OF PAYMENT</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <tr>
          {% for FeesType in SchoolFeesType %}
             <td>{{FeesType.School_Fees_Type}}: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8369; 
                 {{FeesType.Amount}}
             </td>
         {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      </td>

       <td>
        <tr>
          {% for Fees in scheduleofpayment %}   
           <td>{{Fees.Remark}}</td>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      </td>

   </tr>
```

Comment: @MaryRoseVillaganasOrcullo, after copy paste this code where you are getting errors? Actually in your table has one with two columns. so other values since are not related and will contain in two different column which will exist in cascade format. So this nested `<col><row><col>`  format. Since column will be repeated so loop will exist top of the inner column.

Comment: You can't nest a `<tr>` directly inside a `<td>` however, if you add `<table>` inside the `<td>` first, this would work. Which is kind of what I mean by saying "put two tables next to each other", you could embed them in the larger table. However for just one row, I'd just use flexbox to display the two tables.